# Rendering decimals with three decimal places

Tags: android

I am trying to write a program. which round off decimal digits(23.4353353 to 23.435).it is working fine for me.

Problem:-

if i enter 23 only digit no decimal ,it is showing only 23.0.

if decimalvalue is 3:-

i want if any value like 23,40,56 .they should displayed ilke 23.000 ,40.000

```
public class ProjectDecimalActivity extends Activity {
public static EditText et1;
Button btn;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    et1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

}
public void onclick(View v)
{  
    String value = et1.getText().toString();
    int decimalvalue = 3;

    et1.setText(getValue(value, decimalPlaces).toString());
}
public static Float getValue(String value, int decimalvalue)
{
    Float retVal = null;

    try
    {
        float floatValue = Float.parseFloat(value);

        //look for decimal point
        int index = value.indexOf('.'); 
        if (index >= 0)
        {
            String fractional = value.substring(index);

            //do the round off only when the fraction length
            //is greater than decimal places
            if (fractional.length() > decimalvalue)
            {
                floatValue = roundOff(floatValue, decimalPlaces);
            }
        }
        returnvalvalue = new Float(floatValue);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe) 
    {
        //do nothing
    }

    return retVal;
}

public static float roundOff(float value, int decimalPlaces)
{
    float returnvalvalue = value;

    float factor = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < decimalPlaces; i++)
    {
        factor *= 10;
    }

    float roundFactor = 5/(factor*10);
    int intFactor = (int) ((value + roundFactor) * (factor));
    returnvalvalue = (float) intFactor/(factor);

    return returnvalvalue ;
}}
```

my xml code is :-

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onclick"
    android:text="click" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DecimalFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
DecimalFormat threeZeroes = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
double x = 505.0;
String result = threeZeroes.format(x);
Log.i("RESULT", result); // Prints "505.000"
```

Example Depot has [a good collection of examples](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatNum.html) on this topic.

Implement it like so:

```
double decimalValue = Double.parseDouble(value);
String result = threeZeroes.format(decimalValue);
et1.setText(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply can you tell me where should i put this code in my code.

Comment: Well, I'd think you'd be able to understand your code well enough to implement it, but I've given you a bit of help in my post above.

Answer (score 1):

```
et1.setText(String.format("%.3f", getValue(value, decimalPlaces)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DecimalFormat` from `java.text` package.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
double d = 45;
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```